# abbreviations in android via xml or java

Tags: java, android, xml, facebook

first of all.
i have tried searching my question in stackoverflow and not founded the exact answer there are some related questions but those are not the answer of my questions.
may be i dont know what we call that thing which i gonna ask you.

i am creating an xml file in eclipse in which i am going to show abbreviations of words.

for example
    fb: facebook //no new line added for bigger screen
    gm: gmail
    sof: stack over flow

these are just examples.

in my code i want to create 2 textviews or something like that
first textview will show the abbreviations and 2nd will show the exact English for that abbreviation.
but some times on small screens the abbreviation may go out of screen or may include /n or new line and my all other abbreviations will be wrong like this example.

```
fb: face //a new line added for small screen
gm: book
sof: gmail
:stack over flow
```

basically i want you to tell me that how to arrange the code so the textview should either scroll and do not include the new line.
or if textview2 include enter than textview1 should have an enter too.
please help me

Comment: Have you heard about [Table layout?](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)

Comment: Try it, if the `facebook` is too long, it will be wrapped, but next abbreviation will appear under it, on the left, just like in a regular table :) Row after row

Comment: i know i use it in html but dont know that we have a layout in xml too. Thank you Very much you really helped me. but do you know how can we scroll the view horizontally? i mean the textview

Comment: Use ScrollView. It has to contain directly exactly one element, such as TableLayout :)

Comment: yes i use it some times but that scrolls only linear or vertical. i want it to be horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [TableLayout](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) class and [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)
Just try something like this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
            <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <!-- text should go along one line for each row-->
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:stretchColumns="*">

                <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true" 
                            android:text="fb:"/>
                                         <!-- when singleLine atrubutte set : ) -->
                     <TextView
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:singleLine="true"
                           android:text="facebook"/>
                </TableRow>
             </TableLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Does stackoverflow allow us to get each other sky pe address?

Comment: If you are talking about skype id in the SOF profile, then no. If you want to talk with me i have now 00:22 hour (24h) and im not native english speaker :P

Comment: actually i want you to be my friend.

Comment: every developer is mine friend :)